# How to show that $\left \| AB \right \|_F \leq \min (\left \| A \right \|_F \left \| B \right \|_2 , \left \| A \right \|_2 \left \| B \right \|_F)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

For any matrices $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times k}$ and $B \in \mathbb{C}^{k \times n}$, show that $\left \| AB \right \|_F \leq \min (\left \| A \right \|_F \left \| B \right \|_2 , \left \| A \right \|_2 \left \| B \right \|_F)$ where $\left \| \cdot \right \|_F$ and $\left \| \cdot \right \|_2$ are the Frobenius-norm and 2-norm, respectively, defined as:
$\left \| A \right \|_F = \sqrt{\mathrm{trace} \left ( A^H A \right )}$, 
$\left \| A \right \|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_{max} \left ( A^H A \right )}$

Comment: **Hint**: $\|AB\|_F^2 = \mathrm{tr}(A^\star A B B^\star) = \mathrm{tr}(\Lambda U B B^\star U^\star)$ where $A^\star A = U^\star \Lambda U$ with $U$ orthogonal and $\Lambda$ real diagonal. What more do you know about $\Lambda$? What about $U B B^\star U^\star$? Now, proceed.

Comment: @cardinal Nice. Would you care to turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sake of having an answer, let us turn cardinal's comment into one. By definition, $\|AB\|_F^2 = \operatorname{tr}\left((AB)^\ast(AB)\right) = \operatorname{tr}\left(B^\ast A^\ast AB\right)$. Since $A^\ast A$ is positive semidefinite, it has nonnegative eigenvalues and can be unitarily diagonalized as $A^\ast A=U^\ast\Lambda U$, where $\Lambda$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix containing the squared singular values of $A$. Using the property $\operatorname{tr}(XY)=\operatorname{tr}(YX)$, we get $\|AB\|_F^2 = \operatorname{tr}(\Lambda UBB^\ast U^\ast)$. As the diagonal entries of both $\Lambda$ and $UBB^\ast U^\ast$ are nonnegative, we have
$$
\|AB\|_F^2 = \operatorname{tr}(\Lambda UBB^\ast U^\ast)\le(\max_i\Lambda_{ii})\operatorname{tr}(UBB^\ast U^\ast)
=\|A\|_2^2\|B\|_F^2.
$$
Hence $\|AB\|_F\le\|A\|_2\|B\|_F$. The counterpart inequality can be proved by unitarily diagonalizing $BB^\ast$.

Comment: @Sam No, that's not what I meant in the answer. Let $M=UBB^\ast U^\ast$. Then $\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda M)=\sum_k \Lambda_{kk}M_{kk}$. For every $k$, $\Lambda_{kk}\le\max_i\Lambda_{ii}$. Hence the trace is $\le(\max_i\Lambda_{ii})\sum_k M_{kk}=(\max_i\Lambda_{ii})\operatorname{tr}(M)$.

Comment: Yes user1551 you are right. Thank you very much.